# Multiple WHERE conditions in one SQL statement

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I am having trouble to use many `WHERE` conditions, as I do need to combine **8** `Where` conditions in a single statement.

My current SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE ID = ?
```

I want *something* like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE ID = ?, WHERE COL2 = ?, WHERE COL3 = ?, ... WHERE COL8 = ?
```

How can I achieve this? I'm stuck.

Comment: Read a sql Tutorial.

Comment: @Jens There is always a value in questions, even if at first glance they look ridiculous

Comment: See [the offcial MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on `SELECT` - including loads of examples on how to do various things

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot have multiple `WHERE` at the same level of SQL query. You need to use `AND`:

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE ID = ? 
  AND COL2 = ? 
  AND COL3 = ?
  -- ... 
  AND COL8 = ?
```

or use nesting:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM Table
      WHERE ID = ?) s
WHERE COL1 = ?
...
```

---

It is actually an interesting question. For instance [KQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/whereoperator)(Kusto query language) allows to chain multiple `WHERE`:

```
 Tab
 | where col = ?
 | where col2 = ?
```

Sample:

```
let t1 = datatable(key:long, value:string)  
[1, "a",  
2, "b",
3, "c"];

t1 
| where key in (1,2)
| where value == "b"
```

Answer (score 1):

We are not allowed to use the multiple where condition in the same statement. For that you need to approach by using and. 
For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
where col='a' and col2='c' and col'3'
```

This will work perfectly fine.