# mysql search street and street number

Tags: mysql

I have a customer table like this

```
id | city          | street            | street number
1  | Berlin        | Bahnhofstraße     | 5
2  | New York      | Main street       | 22
3  | Frankfurt     | Bahnhofstraße     | 11
4  | London        | Bond Street       | 63
```

I made a simple html input, get the value with jquery and perform an simple search with ajax.

So when i search for "Bahnh" i fire the SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE `street ` LIKE '%Bahnh%' OR city LIKE '%"Bahnh"%'
```

I get the id 1 and 3

But is there a way to add the street number in the query? Like when i search for "Bahnhof 11" i only get id 3?

Comment: Really, you need to look at a Beginners guide to SQL. SO is not a teaching or tutorial site! How much [research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Well i did but cant find any solution for my case

Comment: Well thats obviously not the case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56893793/multiple-where-conditions-in-one-sql-statement

Answer (score 1):

Add a condition

```
SELECT * 
FROM `customers` 
WHERE `street number` = 11 
AND (`street ` LIKE '%Bahnh%' OR city LIKE '%"Bahnh"%')
```

---

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ID, CITY, STREET, STREET NUMBER, CONCAT('STREET', CONCAT(' ', STREET NUMBER)) TEST FROM `CUSTOMERS`)
WHERE TEST LIKE '%Bahnh 11'
```

Comment: but the string given is not 11. Its "Bahnh 11" 
I know i could get the last chars of the given string but the last chars not always the street number

Comment: You can use concat for concat street and street number. And this result put in from to use it.

Comment: The CONCAT solution will return an empty set for '%Bahnh 11'. And what if the user searches for 11 Bahnh? And why do you CONCAT twice and make also a subselect? And CONCAT('STREET' which is a string, not a column. It's plain wrong.

Comment: If you want to use `CONCAT` you can simply write `SELECT * FROM customers WHERE CONCAT(street, ' ', street_number) LIKE '%whatever%'` - but will not solve his search problem.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you have a single search field for address where the user can type both street name and street number. You can create a full text search index on both columns:

```
ALTER TABLE customers 
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX fulltext(street, street_number);
```

Read more about FULLTEXT SEARCH: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Then you have to manipulate the string you search by adding + and * at on every word. The final SQL should look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM streets 
WHERE MATCH (street, number) AGAINST ('+Bahnh* +11*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

`+` means that every word is mandatory, `*` is wild card like `%` in LIKE queries.

**One caveat:** you cannot search inside the string with this SQL, only strings that start with Bahnh* - But it will solve your problem on searches like '11 Bahnh' or 'Bahnh 11' etc...

Answer (score 0):

Just add another criterion to your `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE street LIKE 'Bahnh%' AND street_number = 11;
```

Comment: He doesn't search for the street number in a separate field. He has one input where he types "Bahnh 11"

Comment: Then that should change, and the OP should be asking for the street name and number as separate inputs.